# Providing parameter names for delegate types

Tags: f#, delegates

Is it possible to specify parameter names for delegate types in F#? When I create a delegate of this type in F#:

```
type DataValidationEventHandler = delegate of obj * DataValidationEventArgs -> unit
```

...it auto-generates this signature for the handler in C#:

```
static void loader_ValidationEvent(object __p1, DataValidationEventArgs __p2)
```

Ideally it would generate the usual 'sender' and 'e' parameter names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

```
type DataValidationEventHandler = delegate of sender:obj * e:DataValidationEventArgs -> unit
```

Comment: Bleh. I tried that, but I put parens around 'sender:obj' (as you would in a function signature). Good to know that doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: @Bless Yahu - in C# delegate types always have parameter names - there is no way to omit them.  For example the equivalent C# delegate would be `delegate void DataValidationEventHanlder(object sender, DataValidationEventArgs e)`.
`

Comment: My mistake, I was mistook this on how to provide the xml comments for parameters of delegates.

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
type MyDel = delegate of o:obj * ea:System.EventArgs -> unit
```

names them `o` and `ea`.